# webpack jquery does not work, '$ is not defined'

Tags: jquery, webpack, yarnpkg

I have a separate .js for all scripts and such. At the top I import all needed scripts that I added with webpack/yarn.

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

But since I changed to importing jQuery with webpack instead of linking to the actual jQuery script I get errors in my Firefox console.

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined,
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you need to set the name `$` to be specifically imported from the library, rather than just importing the entire library and relying on side-effects. Try:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

Answer (score 0):

In you configuration file you could use this native plugin:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
    '$': 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method in your `main.js` or `app.js` whichever is your global Javascript file.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```